# Timeseries dataframe returns an error when using Pandas Align - valueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

**My goal:**

I have two time-series data frames, one with a time interval of 1m and the other with a time interval of 5m. The 5m data frame is a resampled version of the 1m data. What I'm doing is computing a set of RSI values that correspond to the 5m df using the `vectorbt` library, then aligning and broadcasting these values to the 1m df using [df.align](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html?highlight=align#pandas.DataFrame.align)

**The Problem:**

When trying to do this line by line, it works perfectly. Here's what the final result looks like:

[image]

However, when applying it under the function, it returns the following error while having overlapping index names:

> ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names

**Here's the complete code:**

```
import vectorbt as vbt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=3)

btc_price = vbt.YFData.download('BTC-USD',
                                interval='1m',
                                start=start_date,
                                end=end_date,
                                missing_index='drop').get('Close')


def custom_indicator(close, rsi_window=14, ma_window=50):
    close_5m = close.resample('5T').last()
    rsi = vbt.RSI.run(close_5m, window=rsi_window).rsi
    rsi, _ = rsi.align(close, broadcast_axis=0, method='ffill')
    print(rsi) #to check
    print(close) #to check
    return

#setting up indicator factory
ind = vbt.IndicatorFactory(
    class_name='Combination',
    short_name='comb',
    input_names=['close'],
    param_names=['rsi_window', 'ma_window'],
    output_names=['value']).from_apply_func(custom_indicator,
                                            rsi_window=14,
                                             ma_window=50,
                                            keep_pd=True)
    
res = ind.run(btc_price, rsi_window=21, ma_window=50)


print(res)
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have no experience with vectorbt, but the name of the series output by `df.align` is (14, 'Close'). If the other name to combine is 'Close', could this be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

if you checked the columns of both , rsi and close

```
print('close is', close.columns)
print('rsi is', rsi.columns)
```

you will find

```
rsi is MultiIndex([(14, 'Close')],
           names=['rsi_window', None])
close is Index(['Close'], dtype='object')
```

as it has two indexes, one should be dropped, so it can be done  by the below code

```
rsi.columns = rsi.columns.droplevel()
```

to drop one level of the indexes, so it could be align,

Comment: This answer worked for me. It looks like `vectorbt` indicators, when preserving pandas dfs (ie. `keep_pd=True`) , creates multi-level indexes to store the indicator values for each unique parameter when calling `run` (ie. `vbt.RSI.run(...`). In this case, `rsi_window` gets interwoven into the index. As @mina-nessim correctly states, this causes an index mismatch when trying to execute the `align`.

Comment: The full `droplevel()` syntax would be:
 `rsi.columns =  rsi.columns.droplevel(level='rsi_window')`, which explicitly removes the multi-index for `rsi_window`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data must be a time series and not a pandas data frame for table joins using **align**
You need to fix the data type

```
# Time Series
close = close['Close']
close_5m = close.resample('15min').last()
rsi = vbt.RSI.run(close_5m, window=rsi_window).rsi
rsi, _ = rsi.align(close, broadcast_axis=0, method='ffill', join='right')
```

Answer (score -2):

When you are aligning the data make sure to include `join='right'`

```
rsi, _ = rsi.align(close, broadcast_axis=0, method='ffill', join='right'
```